# How come only certain tags display a small image?

Tags: support

Examples include android, chrome, and mongodb - they have small pictures on the tag. Why, for example, don't java, postgresql, or excel tags have them?

Can they be added easily?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tags with images in them are [sponsored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean). When a tag has an image, the respective company / individual that "owns" that tag, like Google for Android, can have images placed in tags.

"Generic" tags [aren't available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable/104757#104757) for sponsorship, so they remain imageless.