# What benefits does a sponsor gain from a sponsored tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

Stack Overflow has sponsored tags. These tags have a logo of their relevant company or sponsor, but the benefit to said sponsor is unclear to me. There is additional brand recognition, sure, and I've read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262513/2756409) that the sponsor "owns the tag", but what does that mean, ultimately?

Do sponsors get an income per sponsored tag used? I doubt this, since sponsors have to pay money to get a sponsored tag in the first place.

If I were Google (for example), why would I want to sponsor a tag on Stack Overflow, from a business perspective?

Comment: `There is additional brand recognition` What else do you need?  That's enough for plenty of companies.

Comment: @Servy I'm asking because I want to know, not because I'm looking to sponsor a tag myself.

Comment: Advertisement?? Isn't that what they're buying?

Comment: It would also be intersting to know what benefits SO gains from sponsored tags

Comment: @web-tiki Is your question serious? Money of course. SE isn't keeping SO up just for fun.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The advertising info link in the site footer outlines what is included with [sponsored tags](https://stackexchange.com/mediakit#advertising):

> A tag sponsorship will give your brand logo placement on the tag icon
> (TM holders only) and all the questions featuring that tag. The tag
> homepage will showcase up to 5 text links and a 100x100 logo. The tag
> sponsor will also own a 50% share of all banner impressions targeted
> to the tag question and answer pages.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think to check the footer for info when searching for questions on this.

Answer (score 21):

I am only tangentially involved in our Internet Explorer sponsorship, but one thing I like about it is that we have a centralized place to share helpful things we're working on.

For instance, when we launched our [*streamable* browser](https://remote.modern.ie) for Android, Mac OS X, Windows (and Windows Phone), etc., we were able to link to it from our [Sponsored Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) page. We could also link to our [UserVoice](http://uservoice.modern.ie), [Status](https://status.modern.ie), and more.

Comment: So you (the IE team) have exclusive control over the Tag Wiki page, then?

Comment: @TylerH No. The Tag Wiki page is a wiki - you can edit it too [if you have sufficient rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). We (the IE team) control the Sponsored Links on the tag page.