# NativeScript sponsoring Ionic?

Tags: bug, tags, sponsored-tags

The [ionic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3) which has to do with the Hybrid App Framework [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) seems to be sponsored by [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) which is a different mobile application framework. Although the tag itself does not have the icon as tag sponsorship gives.

Check screenshot:

[image]

I checked the [nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript) which *does have sponsorship*.Also the tag in its questions does have the icon.

[image]

**is this a bug or a rather odd marketing strategy?**

Comment: Isn't this a very common strategy? You google for azure you get ec2's ads etc?

Comment: If it were indeed sponsorship as per the image, the ionic3 tag would have NativeScript icon as well. @ayhan... Tag sponsorship isnt the same as ad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277946/what-benefits-does-a-sponsor-gain-from-a-sponsored-tag

Comment: I am not sure why you assume both the icon and the banner+links should be in the same tag sponsorship package.

Comment: @ayhan You could be right and they can be separate.. Either case, a dev can confirm it. I am just bringing to light what I saw was odd and a potential bug with linking

Comment: These are product names, it is the owner that pays for the advertising.  But they are not the same, NativeScript was owned by Telerik, now Progress Software from Bedford MA.  Ionic is owned by Drifty Co from Madison WI.  Venture capital might be behind it but that's always hard to find out and not so likely since Progress is a big company.  To me it just looks like a mistake made by SO's marketing dept, they do have a knack for getting it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the Ad Ops team here at Stack Overflow.

This tag sponsorship is set up correctly. An advertiser chooses which tags they would like to sponsor for a variety of reasons. Sometimes sponsoring tags in seemingly unrelated technologies depending on what their broader advertising goals are.

Regarding the 18x16 tag logo on the actual tag, an advertiser can only purchase that type of tag logo sponsorship if they hold the trademark to that specific tag name. That is why you see it on the "nativescript" tag, but not any of the other tags that they are currently sponsoring.

Comment: These ads seem downright abusive, especially the "View the docs" link that sounds like it's for Ionic 3 docs but actually goes to a competitor.

Comment: so, in the end, the space above the tag wiki excerpt is a glorified ad location... Otherwise it provides misleading information

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** 
I'd say it's just marketing strategy for NativeScript.

**Conjecture:** 
It also could be that there will be more collaboration between the projects in the future. Ionic is built on Angular, and NativeScript now has support for Angular. There is even [a theme](https://github.com/rdlauer/nativescript-ionic) for NativeScript that makes it [look like Ionic](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/07/give-nativescript-mobile-app-ionic-framework-theme/). It seems conceivable that someone could even make it so that Ionic code could be easily portable to NativeScript.

They've also gone as far as making a whole site ([HybirdToNative.com](http://www.hybridtonative.com/)) dedicated for converting apps from Hybrid (such as Ionic), to NativeScript, so they're obviously trying sway some developers over.

Comment: As you say its all conjecture. One thing that doesnt fit the scenario you suggest is : according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277948/4826457) they would need trademark to do it