# Probable tag sponsoring bug again: Aspose sponsors the [file] and [file-io] tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sponsored-tags

Both the [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) and [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) tags have a sponsor block at the top:

> [image: Aspose "sponsored links for this tag" block on the "Public questions tagged [file] page]

The block is inserted after page load, and neither [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) nor [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) have a sponsorship icon (but that’s not surprising, tag icon sponsoring is only permitted when the sponsor owns the trademark for the tag name).

This happens on a semi-regular basis; the previous two cases:

- [Sponsored tag bug again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373240/sponsored-tag-bug-again)
- [What does data analysis have to do with Angular?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371776/what-does-data-analysis-have-to-do-with-angular)

so I suspect this is another such a bug.

Even so, advertisers [do have more latitude when it comes to placing sponsored links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359198/nativescript-sponsoring-ionic), I just highly doubt that Aspose would expect to have a high click-through rate on two tags *this* generic, when advertising an API aimed at Excel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work with the advertising team here at Stack Overflow. In this instance, Aspose is sponsoring the tags "file" and "file-io" as part of a larger tag sponsorship. The reason that you are not seeing the 18x16 logo on the actual tag, is that we only allow that for advertisers that own a copyright on the name of the tag.

Comment: I know about the icon rule, should’ve made that explicit :-) I’m just *very surprised* that this was a deliberate choice!

Comment: @Cœur Im still seeing the add on the file tag. Perhaps your viewing the site on a small screen/ in responsive mode. There adds are disabled.

Comment: @Luuklag 4k fullscreen. I'll check my ad-blocker, because I've never seen "Sponsored links" actually.

Comment: @Cœur yeah that might well be the case, inspecting the element gives some hints to google ad stuff. pagead2.googlesyndication.com/* for example

Comment: @Luuklag OK, confirmed, it was [privacy-badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) hiding it for me.

Comment: Surely you mean "trademark", not "copyright". Is the actual wording of the policy available, or is it internal?