# Advertisement redirects to a Staff user profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, advertising

There is an advertisement in the Stack Overflow side bar ("Opportunity doesn't knock twice"), when clicking on that it redirects to a Stack Exchange Staff user profile.

It seems a bug to me, or the advertisement is only to redirect a staff user profile?

> [image: SO Ad]

Please find the [URL of the advertisement](https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsv_YO_Y-p0oCxUSuhMGHgbb8PPmCropsanE76sVWry1yZbB1S6BHFlblpykR1y0ea5Pk-EjPMrvimiR-AEgRSD4rbjmb6yZM_tAyF-BiDVt_UNOHw-hZ4sTY6p8zi18q9zLJy9ujLVhtUREF0-drKptlr7i6NkM2mWJe71jaEt_U4gFBz7JSCHgs0sEwjb2CMboqMvm18sn5qSWmT6rD5dyQH0WMI5ZhwmfBKakhnTLRigc1sgqWrgepDCHZahTTDYEOl7twYIgiYcq4Pq13WjcPhlPudiL_m6SwA&sig=Cg0ArKJSzB1RDxhOg_R4&adurl=https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/10443057%3Futm_source%3Dso-owned%26utm_medium%3Dhouse-ads%26utm_campaign%3Djobs%26utm_content%3Dopportunity&nx=142&ny=73) and the [Advertisement image URL](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/12579489488183795130).
It redirects to this [Staff user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10443057/)

Comment: That would be the second time in a short period: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388207/578411

Comment: I don't understand why that is needed. Is the ad system not hooked up to the [dev.stackoverflow.com](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2f) or so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work in Ad Ops at Stack Overflow. The creatives linking to this URL have been temporarily paused while a fix is on the way. Thanks for catching.

Comment: Just before I saw the same advertisement and clicking on it, redirect to jobs page.