# Why does the [python] tag now have a green square next to it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

The issue which appeared in [Why does the [C#] tag now have a green square next to it? What is its significance?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388177/why-does-the-c-tag-now-have-a-green-square-next-to-it-what-is-its-significan) seems to have reappeared, now for the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag instead.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://twitter.com/stahnma/status/634849376343429120

Answer (score 4):

Why do I get the feeling that it is actually being sponsored *this time*?

Because it could be the [Knights who say *"Ni!"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Who_Say_%22Ni!%22):

[image: Knight of Ni from the Monty Python's Holy Grail film, demanding a shrubbery]

If so, can we please tell them to go find their own? We are busy answering questions instead.

Comment: Those who hear them seldom live to tell the tale.

Comment: Maybe someone should reach out to 'Monty' Widenius to sponsor the Python tag...