# The C++ tag (and previously the C tag) is being displayed with a Qt icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

The [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag is being displayed with what appears to be a blurry Qt icon (and the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag is not).

Screenshot of [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info):

[image: C++ tag being displayed with a blurry Qt icon]

Previous issue: [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) (Screenshot below)

[image: C tag being displayed with a blurry Qt icon]

Comment: I repro. And a *terrible*, blurry, pixelated Qt icon at that.

Comment: css class 'sponsor-tag-img'. Did something go wrong, or are companies allowed to sponsor any tag?

Comment: For those, the i.imgur.com is not working/supporting, please check the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Yfc.png)

Comment: @visibleman yes, Oracle could sponsor a microsoft tag. and at this moment in time I don't care who sponsors what as long as they are paying big money for it.

Comment: I wonder whether all the weird things which sometimes happen in any company are caused by "sponsoring". It would explain a lot.

Comment: Also seeing this, and no other tag sponsorship icons? The icon is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKczr.png) but I didn't parse it at all, didn't see the "Qt" until I read this. There is no sponsorship information on the tag page, that I can find. Very confusing, I guess/hope it's a bug.

Comment: That's not appropriate in my eyes, even if Qt might have paid for, as it is not obvious that this resulted from sponsoring. It rather makes the c-tag look like being related to Qt library, even though there's a separate qt tag...

Comment: Example for properly sponsored tag: [sql-server tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info). The icon must fit small dimensions, the Qt team sent SE something that simply doesn't fit, so it's horribly blurred when resized.

Comment: The real fun is that [Qt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTsLGUj0Aiw) is in C++.

Comment: Can't wait for the C# tag to have a small pixelated picture of Jon Skeet next to it

Comment: Given that Qt is a C++ framework and [doesn't even *have* a C interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface), this is almost certainly a bug or human mistake. No need to antagonise over why the image is blurry or why Qt might be sponsoring.

Comment: There have been multiple issues with this in the past, often blamed on the tool that allows SO employees to add the sponsor icon to tags, or with testing in production. I'm sure that this will be fixed soon, that is - if employees still dare look at Meta.

Comment: There have been [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388177/why-does-the-c-tag-now-have-a-green-square-next-to-it-what-is-its-significan) [issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391146/why-does-the-python-tag-now-have-a-green-square-next-to-it) in the past and both were bugs.

Comment: Now the `c++` tag has this bug. I can understand `qt` having the icon but not `c++`

Comment: @drescherjm At least it's the language Qt is written in. Apart from that, it's not any better than before, now it looks as if C++ was a Qt product...

Comment: And it's linked to i.imgur.com instead of i.stack.imgur.com, to boot.

Comment: For the record: to add a tag icon (in addition to just sponsoring it) you're supposed to [own the copyright](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387257/probable-tag-sponsoring-bug-again-aspose-sponsors-the-file-and-file-io-tags/387263#387263) to the tag name.

Comment: Seems kind of odd that QT would sponser the `[c++]` tag but not the `[qt]` tag.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The linked answer does refer to "copyright", but I presume the poster meant "trademark".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem has been corrected. The `c` and `c++` tags no longer show an icon, blurry or otherwise.

Neither of the other answers describes the solution. I'll accept this answer soon unless someone posts a more complete one. For example, it's not clear whether Qt actually attempted to sponsor the `c` and/or `c++` tags (and the bug was that they shouldn't have been permitted to do so), or whether the problem was the result of a bug that caused the icon to be added without involvement from Qt. (The blurriness of the icon is another problem, but one I'm less concerned about unless blurry icons show up on legitimately sponsored tags.)

An explanation isn't absolutely necessary, but I for one am curious. I'd also like some assurance that corporations won't be able to sponsor tags for things they don't own.

Comment: There is still a  "sponsored links" section and a big Qt logo on the c++ tag page itself  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b

Comment: @visibleman At least that's not as bad as having the logo appear on every occurrence of the tag. But it does raise questions about the policy requiring copyright (presumably actually trademark) on a tag name before allowing sponsorship.

Comment: I don't mind that the sponsor link is there, but the tag logo was just awful. I does raise some question as you said.  E.g can Oracle now put sponsored links on the MSSQL tag page?  If so, can sponsored links be used to attack competitors products with links to bad performance test results etc...  (But that is SEs own can of worms that they chose to open I guess)

Comment: I wouldn't mind if the "More Info" page of the C++ tag had a "sponsored by Qt" ad. There's room enough even for multiple sponsors.But this only makes sense for tags that aren't linked to a single company.

Answer (score 15):

Qt doesn't own [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and as [this answer tells](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387263/8548828), it then shouldn't be displayed next to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: Yeah. Qt should be displayed on the Qt tag.

Comment: To be more precise, Qt (the company) also doesn't own the [qt] tag here.

Answer (score -16):

Thanks for pointing this out! We’ve experienced a bug with our internal tool that we use for ad campaigns, this is now fixed. You should see a non-blurry logo appear next to the C++ tag.

**Update Jan 31st, 2020**
We've discussed this policy with the team, and agreed to keep the policy the same. Our partners can only sponsor the tag logo (18x16) if they hold the copyright to that term. They can run sponsored text links (example below) and banners ads on general tags (such as C++ and Security).

[image]

Comment: C++ is not a Qt product. I (and I assume many people) expected the icon to be removed from there, not improved.

Comment: ***You should see a non-blurry logo appear next to the C++ tag*** I would still call that a bug. The non blurry `Qt` icon should only appear on the `Qt` tag.

Comment: I dont think anybody was seriously worried about the blurriness

Comment: Your colleague [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387257/probable-tag-sponsoring-bug-again-aspose-sponsors-the-file-and-file-io-tags/387263#387263) said that one must own copyright to the tag name to be able to change its icon. Is it no longer the case?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat (and others) - Thanks for pointing this out. We're checking whether this policy still applies, and if so: what happened with this campaign. For the time being, we've removed the logo.

Comment: @JD-Stack "We're checking whether this policy still applies" well if you reach the conclusion the policy doesn't apply and the QT logo will appear on the C++ tag that will be really disingenuous and misleading to the site's users. It's fine to have sponsored links on the tag wiki because there is a big "Sponsored links for this tag" header there, but an icon on the tag is another matter entirely. The normal assumption would be that QT **is** the logo of C++ or that QT owns C++ which couldn't be farther from the truth.

Comment: I was about to accept this answer, but it says "You should see a non-blurry logo appear next to the C++ tag." In fact you shouldn't see a logo at all. And in fact you don't. The problem has been fixed (thanks for that), but neither answer describes the actual solution.

Comment: @JD-Stack Do please update once you have clarified this policy. This is an important policy for us users to know.

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica - Thanks for following up :). We're looking into the policy, and will hopefully have consensus at the end of this week. I'll try to get back to you (and the rest) early next week.

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica (and others): I've updated my post above with the policy. Please let me know if this makes sense and whether I should clarify anything else.

Comment: @JD-Stack What does sponsored text link mean? Does that mean when I search C++ I may see an ad in the sidebar for their product?

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica, I've added a screenshot as an example in the message :)