# Excel tag displaying Aspose image

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

The [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag now has an [aspose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspose) logo next to it.

[image]

As [this question about C++](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393168/11936678) states, organisations who do not own the product in the tag should not be able to have their logo displayed next to a tag. This is reinforced by [this official answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387263/11936678). Yet it still happened. Is this a bug, or has the policy been changed?

Comment: Thank you for asking this.... very annoying.

Comment: I'm aware it happens with some frequency because I still remember the last time this question was asked. But it never affected **me** personally, so obviously I need to whine about it on the internet. Seriously though half the reason for asking is just to point it out to someone who might be able to sort it in case they aren't aware.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I'm looking into it, will report back here

Comment: Now the "ms-word" tag is also displaying Aspose too.

Comment: Not only that, I'm seeing a big Aspose ad across the top of the screen when viewing (for example) a set of tags containing [ms-word] - also very annoying!

Comment: [excel] is fixed for me now.  Still seeing the logo on [ms-word] (caching???)

Comment: FWIW Besides on the MS Word tag, I'm also seeing it on the openxml and openxml-sdk tags. And while Aspose *bases* on Word Open XML, it's *not* the Open XML SDK - indeed, it's "competition". @JD-Stack

Comment: Shouldn't there be some person at the company who has to approve this? Surely it can't be some automated process that any 3rd party can abuse.

Comment: Next you're going to start talking about *testing*, @TylerH, and then we'll *know* that you've gone mad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks again for pointing this out. As some of you have spotted already the logo has been removed from the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag, the same will happen with [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) and other tags that the client does not own the copyright for. This is a bug in our system, we're working to create a solution for this.

**Update Feb 14th**
All the logos from tag that do not have copyright are been removed today.

Comment: FYI: I assume that same bug is what is affecting other tags, for example the SendGrid logo next to all of these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEakA.png

Comment: @BigBen - correct. These are removed :)

Comment: Have you been able to identify the root cause of this issue? It has been happening a lot recently that company logs are appearing on unrelated tags, and it's been clearly established that that is in opposition to company policy. Is there some kind of automated tool for this that is broken? Are these being manually reviewed by staff, who might benefit from a clarification on the policy? How can we stop this from continuing to happen and needing to be whack-a-moled each time?