# SendGrid logo attached to email, mail, gmail type tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

It seams that a large number of tags have been infected with the send grid logo.

it appears to be mostly related to email, mail, gmail type tags.

[image]

I am not sure if this is related to [Excel tag displaying Aspose image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393818/excel-tag-displaying-aspose-image) so i thought i would just pop it up here and let you decide.

Its been like this for a few days.

[image]

I have had word from a dev rel at Google are not changing the Gmail logo to that of sendgrid.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393124/10871073 Comment there that, to have your icon on a tag you need to own the copyright to that tag name. Who owns the copyright to "email-address?"

Comment: And there are five "sendgrid-xxx" tags that **don't** have the icon??

Comment: Its also Gmail tags and I have already checked with someone at Google they are not changing their logo to that of sendgrid.  

Comment: It is also on `smtp` and `amazon-ses`. Either this is a bug, or SO as let go of their 'you need to own the product you sponsor'-rule. I'm not sure if Google and Amazon will be amused by SendGrid 'hijacking' their tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! We've removed these logos from the tags that are not "Owned" by the client. More info can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393818/excel-tag-displaying-aspose-image)