# What's going on with the [google-roads-api] tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

[image]

What is that ugly and blurry *Facebook-like* logo that was added to the [google-roads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-roads-api) tag on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It is called *Marketing*...

Comment: How fun, it's yet another sponsored tag bug.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery any official information on what these *sponsored tags* are? I don't seem to see any other logo on any other tag on SO.

Comment: ["Our partners can only sponsor the tag logo (18x16) if they hold the copyright to that term."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393170/7795130). There's some more information over at [How can I set an icon on a tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251364/7795130)

Comment: Looks like it's popping up on a bunch of ad-related tags too. So far I've seen [tag:ads], [tag:admob], [tag:adsense], [tag:interstitial], [tag:banner-ads], [tag:native-ads]

Comment: @DavyM a greyed-out answer voted -15 is not really what I call official information but anyway...

Comment: @MrUpsidown That came from a SE employee, the downvotes are because they were fixing it incorrectly as you can see in the comments but the other info is correct.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery OK. Then what's the bug here? Wrong sponsor? Wrong logo? Both?

Comment: The downvotes were largely due to the first revision where they tried to "fix" the issue by simply including a less pixelated logo (The issue was C++ had an unrelated logo, hence the downvotes because they missed the point). The information I linked was introduced in the second revision, when they started getting it right.

Comment: @DavyM yup, got that. I didn't know if that user was really a SE employee or not...

Comment: @MrUpsidown Usually when this happened in the past it's because a tool or database update went wrong. Hard to say what was supposed to happen until they fix it.

Comment: For future reference, Staff have an orange box on their usercard (hover over their profile image) as well as on their user page that indicates that they are employees.

Comment: *Our partners can only sponsor the tag logo (18x16) if they hold the copyright to that term.* - I doubt FB holds the copyright for `google-roads-api` or I got this wrong. So it looks like a double bug... bad logo and wrong sponsor.

Comment: Yup, you nailed the crux of the issue with that comment. This happens a lot though (several times a year for something that you wouldn't think would be buggy), so we'll just wait until a staff member sees your question and goes in and fixes it. To see some of the history, look at the meta tag [meta-tag:sponsored-tags].

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question to include that tag too.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277946/what-benefits-does-a-sponsor-gain-from-a-sponsored-tag

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for letting us know, looks like this was just a human mistake, we’re removing the tag sponsorship

Comment: I see another one: [[tag:flurry]] -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flurry

Comment: Thanks @TylerH, that one (and some others) is removed as well :)