# What else should I do when I vote to reopen a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I recently posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) where I complained about Java developers closing Processing questions as duplicates of Java questions.

For example, sometimes functions internal to Processing will throw a `NullPointerException` if the library is in the incorrect state. The line number in the error is often misleading, since it refers to compiled Java code instead of Processing code. This is not the "typical" cause of a `NullPointerException` (nor is the solution the same), so these questions should **not** be closed as duplicates of the canonical Java NPE question. Despite that, many Java developers close these types of questions without even reading the question or noticing the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag.

My meta post got some attention and some great answers with interesting suggestions. But then... nothing really happened as a result.

Then today, it happened again. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767012/null-pointer-exception-with-curvepoint-in-processing-org) asks about a `NullPointerException` internal to Processing. This is not the same as an NPE in user code, and the OP even says that they printed out the values of all of the variables on that line, and none of them are null. But it was still closed as a duplicate of the canonical Java NPE question.

This is frustrating, but okay, the best I can do is vote to reopen. But from experience, that's not going to do much: the people looking at the reopening review queue will just see that the post contains a `NullPointerException`, and vote to keep it closed as a duplicate of the Java NPE question.

**So, how can I help reopen questions like this?**

**Option 1:** I could leave a comment explaining why it should be reopened. The problem is that the people in the reopening review queue don't seem to see these comments.

**Option 2:** I could edit the question to include a blurb about it being a Processing question, not a Java question. This is what I did, but it just looks sorta gross.

**Option 3:** I could post a meta question every time this happens. You guys will be hearing from me several times a week though.

**Option 4:** I could just tell the OP to resubmit the question without the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. This is by far the worst option, but by far probably the most effective solution. The fact that this is my best option seems like a problem with how things currently work.

I realize that this would be a non-issue if I myself had the ability to reopen these questions (which I believe you earn after getting a gold badge in a language tag), but unfortunately Processing doesn't have enough questions for **anybody** to have that ability yet.

Comment: Pinging the user that closed the question is a good start. They can reopen the question with a single vote. I left a comment.

Comment: @Tunaki That's exactly what I tried, but since I didn't get an autocomplete popup (and your @ mention isn't a link) I didn't think the user would get a notification that I mentioned them. If they do get a notification, that's exactly what I'll do in the future.

Comment: Yes, they do. You have the documentation of the @ feature here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work: *For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question*

Comment: for close voters and editors there is no auto-complete. Just make sure you type carefully  ;)  ....

Comment: You should get on Processing and tell them their error messages suck ass.  They need to do more checking and throw custom exceptions with more details, anyhow.  A framework throwing simple NREs?  That's utterly awful.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks, this is good to know. This is perfect! If you want to post it as an answer for the sweet sweet uncounted meta upvotes, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Also remember to remove spaces when manually typing the user name.

Comment: Could you add another answer to the NPE question to describe what to do for questions about [tag:processing]. That would mean the standard duplicate is applicable. The alternative: Getting even all Java experts to understand the distinction would be difficult but many close voters seeing the NPE will not be Java experts and not know anything about [tag:processing].