# My program exits immediately. No, I've never heard of "main", why do you ask?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a couple of new questions in the last two days which are exactly of the form "this wall of code exits immediately, why?" and there is no method/function `main`.  What's the proper flag or other action (with my low rep I think I can only flag)?

Comment: Seems like there's probably a duplicate for that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You mean for this meta-question?  I sort of looked for one but didn't find it.  My SO search-foo is poor, though.

Comment: No, I mean for the questions in question.

Comment: There are some questions/dups about 'two mains'.  If only the programs with two main() functions could be married up to the ones with none...

Comment: Downvote.  Leave a comment.  If you can vtc, vtc as no repro.

Comment: close as "typo" I would. such quetions are very unlikely to ever help another user -- someone having the same problem, and someone having the intelligence to search for it, are mutually exclusive states

Comment: How do they link such things?

Comment: We have a close reason for that: [_"1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MartinJames - what is this "link" you refer to?  -- a typical Java programmer

Comment: You seem to take it as self-evident that the question you've described warrants some moderation action. Can you make it more evident to the rest of us what problem you see with such a post?

Comment: I'm not sure I realized the implication that the flag (or other action) required moderator interaction.  I guess I kind of thought there might be a way to save everyone's time by marking it immediately as a faq or something.

Comment: Let's just hope these questions are not [written in Processing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).