# Are these tags relevant to the question?

Tags: support, tags

I tagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740701/problem-with-messages-always-info-and-for-not-honored?noredirect=1#comment119737293_67740701) with the tags `java`, `java-7` and `messagebox`, because I'm using Java 7 and the question is about message boxing with PrimeFaces.

A user removed these tags.

Are these tags relevant to the question?

Comment: The tags were not removed by a moderator but by an expert user.

Comment: Is the Java version important when the question is about JSF? Or is it more likely that you have certain version restrictions for JSF itself and not necessarily for Java? (I don't work with JSF, so I don't know)

Comment: @Tomerikoo: whops, I was wrong, sorry.

Comment: The user that edited also commented on your question: *"Your questions cannot be answered by Java experts. They can be answered by JSF experts"*. I think before posting here you could ask them by pinging them in a comment

Comment: @Tomerikoo since this is not the first time the user remove tags from my question, I want an expert opinion about it

Comment: @Tom: yes, I'm stuck to `Java` 7 and `Primefaces` 3.4.1

Comment: Did you ping them about it in other occasions?

Comment: Why not tagging with Windows, since you are also using it? :thinking:

Comment: @Braiam The app that has this problem can run also on Linux, but not without Java 7. Furthermore it's a problem about message boxes or not?

Comment: @MarcoSulla I understand that you're required to use Java 7, but when an answer uses JSF, how can it invalidate that restriction? Can it contain features that don't work with Java 7? So I assume the answer should work with the necessary JSF and Primefaces version, and the Java version is unimportant here.

Comment: @Tom So I can't add the tag `java` even if the program is written in Java?

Comment: @Tom See this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742200/guzzle-errors-php-8-handle-must-be-of-type-curlhandle-null-given : `php` and `php-8` tags must be removed?

Comment: Using other questions as example of "why X can do it but mine can't" can get very ugly very fast. Please, don't use questions that haven't been properly vetted to argument your behavior.

Comment: Ok, but I simply do not understand why a question with Java code can't be tagged with `java`

Comment: Marco, like I said, I don't use JSF, so I don't know how strong it is coupled to Java itself, or if it can be considered something independent. Like you wouldn't tag an Angular question with Javascript. That is why I asked if Java restrictions really apply to that question. I can't tell.

Comment: If your issue can be demonstrated and fixed in a static main method, you can tag it as Java. For anything else, the question cannot be answered unless you have knowledge of the used framework (JSF in this case). So the Java tag is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the tags used on a question, you should determine which knowledge is more likely needed to be able to answer it. Merely using a language isn't enough to clear this hurdle.

Experts on tags would remove tags if they aren't able to answer it. The best result is if said experts is capable of adding a tag which is more relevant to your question, but usually this is not the case when there's not enough details on the question itself. If an expert finds that the question is about topics that are not represented in the tags, they could try to add the relevant ones.

All in all, merely using something, doesn't mean that your question is about it. Otherwise, [all these Django questions would also have python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+-python) merely because Django was written in Python, whenever or not it was relevant to the problem in the question.

Comment: So in what case you can use the `messagebox` tag? There should be an expert in message boxes?

Comment: @MarcoSulla think about it critically, there's something you should know for knowing about messageboxes right? Like the library that implements them, or the framework, right? The argument that I exposed in my answer works not only laterally, but also vertically.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb I like to apply to situations like this is the [Processing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) rule.

Processing is a convenient example and a pretty sterling example of "needs a different expert", because even though the syntax *looks* like Java, it...*isn't* Java, and so someone tagging a question with both [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) would hurt a Java expert's soul.

In this case, though, JSF (or Java/Jakarta Server Faces) is [pretty darn close to Java](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsf-example), with some caveats.  To be honest it reminds me a lot of [Thymeleaf through Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc), and it'd be a tough sell in my mind to demonstrate that somehow this *isn't* Java.

To put even the average asker in context, you even provided what looks like a snippet of Java code.  (It'd be nice if it were more complete, but these days I celebrate what I can get.)  I don't disagree that at first blush it'd mean that a Java expert wouldn't have a clue what's going on, but that doesn't meant that the code *isn't* Java.

All that said, though...I largely agree with Braiam's points about using the right tag to get the right experts.  In this case, you *wouldn't* want to tag this with Java, since my ignorant self would try to come in and approach this from a Java perspective, which isn't the kind of help you need.  As a real-time example, mentioning Java 7 makes me bristle quite a bit and I don't understand why you *have* to use it, but in context for an expert, there's probably a rational explanation.